# ssh getting stuck at debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<3072<8192) sent

Tags: ssh, openssl, openssh

```
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-md5 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-md5 compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<3072<8192) sent
```

I tried solution mentioned here [ssh stuck on SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<7680<8192) sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185396/ssh-stuck-on-ssh2-msg-kex-dh-gex-request102476808192-sent) but nothing working.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issue where server were expecting 34 type of Diffie-Hellman Group exchange when using diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 and the client was only able to use the old 30 type. As we couldn't switch the client (embedded in other code) we had to use other diffie-hellman-group14-sha1. In your case group14 doesn't seem to be common, but you have this in common: "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1", which may work better. Else try to change client and try different clients to see if that helps.

```
/* dh-group-exchange */
#define SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST_OLD         30
#define SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP           31
#define SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT            32
#define SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY           33
#define SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST         34
```